# On bibliographic references.

Tags: discussion, policy, reference-request

On this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1038/274), which provides a bibliographic reference to one of the standard sources of information on the subject of question to which it is attached, was flagged for review for «low quality» and, in response to that, two users added comments complaining about it being a «link-only» answer and so on.

Even if that answer were the only answer to the question —and in fact there are several answers, each providing different pieces of the story— I find the review and the comments simply absurd, specially when «rules» are used to support them.

While it is true that an answer which is only a link is not usually a very good answer, can we *please* use a generous amount of common sense before turning that into a rule?

Comment: The first comment is perfectly sensible. The second one is, as you know, fixed and close enough.  Worth noting, the question was not originally tagged reference request.  Would this happen now your answer would be removed or converted to a comment with high likelihood.  The fact that you mention a standard reference rather speaks against your answer not in favor of it. (On the good side, you mentioned at least the volume.)

Comment: That it is the standard reference does not at all mean that people know about it. I would say that most people do not even know that the book exists, quid.

Comment: I honestly cannot believe one has to explain that providing a bibliographic reference to a scholarly work that **exactly** answers what is a scholarly question on a website dedicated to a scholarly subject is a perfectly good and sensible answer.

Comment: And that the question is not marked as a reference request is entirely irrelevant — I'd say that it only reflects on the fact that the original asker did not even think to ask for a standard reference on the history of notations (most probably because he did not even imagine there is such a thing)

Comment: Finally, if the comment is fixed and not appropriate (and no, it is not "close enough" in any meaningful sense) then it should not be used. If a user cares so much, then she should be able to muster the energy to write a comment which makes sense on the specific situation.

Comment: You do know how the review queues work, right?

Comment: It forces people to use text that does not apply to situations?! It seems you have not picked up my point, which was that the review itself was absurd and should have been ignored.

Comment: I recommend you calm down  a bit and reconsider the situation in a day or two. Try to answer what was unreasonable about the request to *expand* your answer (explaining in what specific way the reference will answer the question that OP asked).

Comment: You are kidding me, right? The question asks for a history lesson on the history of the notation for derivatives, Cajori wrote half a tome on precisely that, and my answer quite clearly states that the asker will find a precise description of the history of the notation for derivatives in his book: how more specificly can one explain that the book will answer the question? What on earth does "expand the answer" mean in this situation?

Comment: So, you believe to recommend to read half a book to get an answer to this question is a useful answer? Are you kidding me?:-)

Comment: Of course I do believe that giving a reference to an in depth treatment of a question is a useful answer. I have read most of that book and I have found it extraordinarily useful, and I am most certain that anyone interested in the history of the notation of calculus will find it just as useful (and beautiful) as I did.

Comment: I think that a lot of stuff from eight years ago can be treated with much less scrutiny.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, the point of this meta post, though, is that I am suggesting that along with the extra scrutiny (?) that more recent posts are treated with, extra common sense should be applied.

Comment: Mariano, yes I understand that. I was just making a general remark, that I don't think that we should be even looking at stuff from eight years ago with the same critical eye that we do about stuff posted in the last week.

Comment: @Asaf I actually agree with this. The problem though is that Mariano seems to think that his answer is to good to be improved, and makes a fuss about it. I mean he also could just have ignored it. Or, said something along the lines what you said. But,  he insists today this is a good answer.

Comment: @Mariano that's all good and well. Still common sense would seem to dictate to accompany this recommendation with some more guidance, especially, as the question seemed rather to the naive end and you answer was the first one (that's now moot, though). It also asked about specific examples. It was not even a pure history question. I will not continue this debate any further, but this "culture" that your answer there embodies is in my opinion a root-cause for many of the problems we have.on this site

Comment: My answer is part of a culture that holds going to the library, looking into the table of contents of a book and reading it. A good 50% of all the math I know I know because people who know much more than I do gave me references to read on various subjects that solved problems I had, so if you think that my answers embody that, then I cannot but be a bit proud, as I learnt this from really great mathematicians and I strive to share that with others. I find it extraordinary (and absurd) that a pertinent bibliographic reference may embody the root-cause of anything, to be honest.

Comment: And yes, I think today just as I thought at the moment that that is a good answer. I have given reference to that particular book many times to many people and in many different contexts and I have observed that it tends to be useful.

Comment: So I guess we should start providing more answers along the lines of  "See the Student Solutions Manual to [textbook]."

Comment: @palladiumtelemann, If you cannot see the difference belween pointing to the solution of an exercise in a soutions manual and providing a reference to a scholarly book dedicated to the history of notations, which dedicates some 100 pages to telling the history of the notations for derivatives, in a question asking about, among other things, the history of those notations, I will probably not be able to be of help in understanding this point. I am sorry.

Comment: In other words, there is a difference between saying «there are some situations in which providing a bibliographic reference makes perfect sense» and «all questions can sensibly be answered with a bibliographic reference». If you are interested indebating the second of these, you can start another meta thread. Quantifiers, quantifiers, quantifiers.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I quote [one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/on-bibliographic-references#comment114317_28021) of your multiple comments to Aloizio Macedo's answer below: "Referring a person to a book is a sensible answer in any context — this site and elsewhere." I see no limitations in that statement. In fact, it quite explicitly states that references to books are _always_ sensible as answers on [math.se].

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez So, if you don't want to have that debate (that you started), perhaps you should make your position on this matter more clear.

Comment: If you understood that I am advocating that all questions can be sensibly answered with references, I honestly do not know what to tell you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, this of course turned into a series of close votes and downvotes on 5 year old questions of mine, answered and all… Hard hammering on this imperishable optimism of mine that makes me expect common sense.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, what I find surprising and discouraging is the obvious quest for unanimity.

Comment: Well. Some people would think this is just petty, others would just want to flex their muscles, and sometimes people just have an inherent dislike towards someone, and they feel the need to be on the other side of whatever that person is saying, using whatever meta issues as fuel for that fire.

Comment: Just FYI, the book given by Mariano in his answer is easy to find on the Internet, if you know some websites where these kind of books are available.

Answer (score 10):

I think you yourself see the problem with the answer, as you prelude it with:

> If you have access to it, (...)

As I understand, content in MSE should be as self-contained as possible. This "policy" is one of the reasons why images are deprecated, for example. The fact that it is "one of the major works on the history of notation" is **irrelevant**, in my opinion. In a few years, it may be less widespread, copies may be lacking. Also,  acessibility depends on where you are etc. For instance, I've just made a search on the author in the [database of UFRJ](https://minerva.ufrj.br/F?RN=879014784) (Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro) for books on *every library in all campi*, and made hits for

- An introduction to the modern theory of equations.
- Sir Isaac Newton’s mathematical principles of natural philosophy and his system of the world
- A history of elementairy [sic] mathematics with hints on methods of teaching
- Storia della fisica elementare con l’evoluzione dei laboratori fisici
- A history of mathematics

The book you mention is not on the list. This illustrates the problem nicely, I believe.

That said, your answer may be good (none of the above says otherwise. It only argues that it may be inacessible now for some, or that its acessibility may change with time, which are not good things for one of the goals of MSE of a self-contained body of knowledge I believe). But if you interpreted that "the question asks for a history lesson on the history of the notation for derivatives, Cajori wrote half a tome on precisely that", then the problem is with **the question being too broad**. The description of the "too broad" close vote changed, but previously it had a fragment which said:

> (...) good answers would be too long for this format. (...)

It seems that it was changed partly because "too long" is not very precise and may seem to frown upon long but objective answers (more information [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291819/close-the-loop-on-too-broad-make-the-close-reasons-actual-intent-reflected-i)). But certainly, if you think that referring a book for a person to read about is the best answer in this platform, I think that you consider the question to be too broad (and I agree with this. Were it not for the fact that the question is 8 years old, I would vote to close it).

Comment: No, that I use that phrase does not mean at all that I see a problem with my answer. At most, it might mean that I see a problem with the libraries available to the asker and/or her abilities to find scans of the book online. If she or anyone wanted does not have access to the book, I could even send them the scans myself. I have sent the book by email to someone who did ask for it, who learned about its existance through an answer of mine, very similar to this one, to a question on MO.

Comment: And even if some users do not have access to the book, and have no access to the internet, and to email to ask me for the files, *other* users do. It is often the case that I and others write answers not directly for the benefit of the original poster but of others: this may be because the answer depends on access to a book, like in this case, or because it depends on knowing math which the OP probably doees not know, or something. That something is «inaccessible for some» does not mean that it is inaccessible for all: some answers may be not very useful for some, and yet useful for others.

Comment: So no, your hypothesis that I myself see "the problem" with the answer does not hold.

Comment: «As self-contained as possible» does not, simply because it cannot, mean «self-contained».

Comment: Finally, I coul not possibly imagine why a question asking for a history lesson on mathematical notations it too broad because "good answers would be too long for this format" since —this is my point, precisely— a good, pertinent refernce to the literature on the subject can well be an excellent starting point for the OP to set out on the (long) enterprise of learning that, and can be provided in a few lines.

Comment: I think that your arguments seem to prove that this is an inappropriate question **for this site**, as I argue in the last paragraphs of this answer. If the question entails having an answer for which one of the ways to "make it work" could involve sending scans to the interested parts, I think it is not a good question (**for MSE**). Note that I am not saying that the question is bad, or that the book is bad. I've never read the book, and if you claim that it is an excellent reference, I honestly believe it. I just don't believe that this is proper to the environment that is MSE (continuing.)

Comment: Referring a person to a book is a sensible answer in any context — this site and elsewhere. I honestly cringe at the idea that in a site filled with people learning math, that a question have as a sensible answer a reference to a book magically turns the question into one which is not appropriate for the site. I don't know what math this site might be about if that were the case.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, if you met a student in the corridor, or someone sent you an e-mail, or a colleague asked for a reference to the history of the notation of derivatives, your recommendation is probably (and by that, I honestly mean **most certainly**) the best answer among the answers that were given in that post by far. The problem is specifically about how we understand MSE, and what we expect from answers (**not as quality**, but other aspects). I may be wrong in how I see these issues. I think this depends on the community point of view as a whole, so let's wait for some feedback.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo From what you have written, it seems to be that the problem is not with the **answer**, but about the **question**, which is overly broad and invites either pages upon pages of discourse, or a terse reference to a better source of information.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, again: I find it incomprehensible that a question that invites a reference to a well-established, 'better' source of information would make a question a bad fit for this site. For one thing, it is quite possible that someone asking a question does not even imagine that (for example, in this concrete case) there are historians of notation who write entire books about them. As a criterion it would be extremely weird. Would you say that a question about a diophantine equation would be a bad fit for this site if someone could actually prove that any proof of nonexistence (…)

Comment: (…) of solutions must necessarily be very, very long? In other words, are we to judge a question —usually asked by people who do not know the answer— by the fact that the answers to it are long and people write entire books about it?

Comment: @XanderHenderson In my opinion, the question has a problem *because* the answer that Mariano gave was arguably the most appropriate (in terms of answering the question), and that answer is *not* appropriate to MSE (as I conjecture the community thinks, for the reasons stated in this answer, which I feel are very strong ones). I think there is two points of view here for this question: a naive question unknowingly expecting an *a posteriori* answer, or a question expecting a real historical reason to **why** the notation is so.

Comment: Mariano interpreted the question in the later way (as did I), and I think that this is a question way too broad for this site (which Mariano disagrees with). I respect this opinion, and I think there is a worthy discussion to be made. For instance, this attitude (of discouraging those questions/answers) may result in good quality questions not having place when it would be good for this site and community. However, what I am trying to point out is that *there are valid points for not wanting reference-only answers*. I disagree with Mariano's stance of treating this as an absurd.

Comment: That said, I forgot to address an important point that Mariano alluded to in his post: I disagree with flagging his answer as "low quality". Maybe the users did so because they had no other button to mark, or because they are conflating quality with adequateness. But, conjectures aside, I don't believe it should have been flagged at all. Which is not to say that I think it doesn't have any issues, as I explained in this answer.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo unfortunately OP is written in a misleading way. As a matter of fact the post was never flagged as  "very low quality". It was flagged as "not an answer," which is the recommended flag for "link only" answers.  (The review queues then are the same though.) Maybe it should not have been flagged as NAA either, but since the issue of which flag is appropriate came up I thought I mention it. Finally, the first comment on main does not come from the queue so the meta post is also misleading in that regard.

Comment: @quid, since I sincerely think that whether it was NAA or low quality flag is entirely errelevant: if you understand the point I am trying to make, you already know that both fall within the lack of common sense that I am referring to, I did not even look at the flag reason. Saying that what I wrote is misleading carries the evident connotation that it is written to mislead: that is something that could be found insulting by anyone not already immune to dramatic innuendos. If you think there is a factual error which has any relevance to the substance of the post, then you can edit it & fix it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez once you calmed down, I might continue to discuss with you. As said, I have at the moment no interest to discuss this matter with you. (I did not mean to imply that you intended to mislead. If I would, I'd write that 'OP is written in a way to mislead.')

Comment: @quid, Repeatedly saying "when you calm down" is also something that could certainly be found insulting, you know, if it were not a rather infantile attempt at that. To be honest, I would have imagined you were above such rhetoric devices (it is an close relative to calling women 'emotional' in debates, for example). Oh well.

Comment: A note independent of MSE and all. I am quite amazed by your argument here. Books have become not less available with time buy immensely more available, just as papers. Today, without even standing up from a chair, one can reach such an immense amount of such texts that it is simply breath taking. From books to scans of very old papers to everything imaginable. With but a bit of googling-foo, one can access even scans of 200 year old papers that ten years ago would have been impossible to get hold of except by taking a plane to an European country and going to the correct library!

Comment: I started doing math before this was possible: I know how it was. This is why I find it immensely discouraging to see that people do not make as much of what they have available as they could. More and more often I find myself writing comments here asking «have you googled?», usually because I myself can find the answer to questions as the very first google result in the most obvious query —usually just give the title of the question and voilà. Years ago, I have had books brought to my uni as library loans from quite afar… the idea that *today* a reference to a book is becomes bad because

Comment: books «become less accesible« is simply extraordinary!

Comment: Comparing to a time with different technology is missing the point of what I mean with diminishing acessibility of *physical* (or even electronic, but bought) books with time. And again, you dismiss the locality factor. To give yet another example, "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" from Rudin, one of the most prestigious and well-known books on introductory real analysis (arguably **the** most) is at the time of this writing R$701 (USD ~216), with only one on stock in amazon.br. The ability (or better, willingness) to use google is not really related to the discussion here.

Comment: "the idea that today a reference to a book is becomes bad because books «become less accesible« is simply extraordinary!" That is not at all what I am saying, since you implicitly assume that I am talking that this is the case "globally". I am talking about **the specific environment of MSE**. Rewriting what you wrote more accurately, what I am saying is that '**in MSE** a reference to a book becomes bad because, among other reasons, books can «become less accesible«(...)'.

Comment: Note also the "among other reasons", because there are blatant issues which I did not discuss such as the (very relevant) issue of reference chains, where you can usually end up following references up to one which does not answer your question, or maybe answers it poorly (or even wrongly). This chain can be contaminated by paywalls or other obstacles, which makes the process even more frustrating. I didn't mention it because I didn't think it applies to this particular example, but is yet **another** reason to be wary of reference-only answers.

Comment: Being self-contained, one can check the properness of the answer immediately, and also with other peers of the platform at large in a seamless manner. Being a site of people learning math, this collective aspect is important. Reference-only answers can be argued to disencourage that.

Comment: I simply cannot believe "a reference to a book" can become bad here **in MSE** — there is no need to bolden anything, as that is what we are talking about. I am honestly baffled at the notion — whatever specificity MSE may have, it is simply an extraordinary idea.

Comment: I felt the need to bolden since you prefaced your comments with "A note independent of MSE (...)", and then you implicitly mix your observations in the end with the issue at hand. You repeatedly say that you find all this "extraordinary, absurd, baffling, amazing", but you haven't adressed satisfactorily (in my opinion) the issues (at least 4 - namely, local dependence of usefulness of answer, convoluted means of effectiveness, reference-chain problematica, individual utility of the answer, but there are more) that I raised, except from the availability issue, which I think was misconstrued.

Comment: And I didn't make this clear, but I don't think this is a binary situation. What I claim is that -in general-, reference-only answers should be discouraged for the reasons stated in the answer and comments. And, when done, they should probably be accompanied with some sort of discourse of what happens in said reference to attenuate the effects that I mentioned as much as possible.

Comment: Saying that a book "has a pretty detailed description of the history of notations for derivatives in its second volume" is a pretty good description of what happens in a reference that consists, in the parts relevant to the question being answered, of a detailed description of the history of notations — recounting that detailed history of notations in the answer, even in a very sketchy form, would be an absurd (and in fact would actually counter the actual intention of the answer, which is to have people read a book)

Comment: Given that, I have to say that if your arguments are against a pure bibliographic reference —an answer that consisted exactly of «Cajori, Florian A history of mathematical notations. Including Vol. I. Notations in elementary mathematics; Vol. II. Notations mainly in higher mathematics. Dover Publications, Inc., New York, 1993. Vol. I: xvi+451 pp. and Vol II: xii+367 pp.»— then I honestly have no idea in what way they relate to this meta post.

Comment: That last comment is just a straw man. Regarding the previous one, your discourse essentially says "This book answers your question thoroughly". This is not what I intend to mean with "discourse of what happens in said reference". For instance, as an example, suppose that someone asked "What is a proof for the Weierstrass theorem on approximation of continuous function for polynomials?" (regardless if this is ontopic or not, just first example I had in mind). There is a difference between: "Principles of Mathematical Analysis, by Walter Rudin, has a pretty detailed proof of this." (...)

Comment: (...) and "You can find a full proof on Principles of Mathematical Analysis, by Walter Rudin. There, it is made a convolution with a particular polynomial which is highly concentrated around the origin so as to minimize the distance between the original continuous function and the resulting polynomial of said convolution. Some care must be made on the estimates to guarantee that everything goes well." This is the kind of discourse that attempts to escape a bit from complete outside reference.

Comment: @aloizio, I am baffled that you cannot see a difference between sketching a proof for a result which in full form takes a page and referring to a 100 pages. To be honest, I am quite discouraged.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I see a difference, but it was an example to illustrate what I meant with "some sort of discourse of what happens in said reference". I thought that the difference of situations would be irrelevant for the point I was trying to make. Perhaps this example is better: you've given an answer to a [very similar question in spirit](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24242/59234). This answer is what I have in mind when I say "some sort of discourse of what happens in said reference". And I think that all your arguments here would apply ipsis litteris to this question/answer.

Comment: I have stopped caring, to be honest. I don't think this discussion is worth the effort: I find the whole thing absurdly silly and immensely discouraging. My vocabulary is not enough for me to describe how incredibly incomprehensible is to me the idea that giving a pertinent reference can be construed as problematic. Simply and literally incomprehensible.

Comment: Today I looked for an answer I had written a few days ago and could not find it: it turned out that the question on which it was posted had been deleted — deleted for pretty much the same reasons that spurred the flag that motivated this thread. I am sorry to say that if content is going to be treated with such absurd criteria I will probably simply stop providing it. I am sorry because I have fun writing answers, but if there is not a modicum of respect on the content I'll go back to freenode or something as soon as it stops being a pleasure do to it

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That is OK, I respect that. But could you please just consider this answer I linked? Consider if you think that it is different in any relevant way from the one you linked, what motivated you to answer like that, and if you think it is more appropriate or not. Also, if you think pragmatically, what answer do you think would motivate one the most to read the book? (Again, I disagree with any sort of deletion/flagging. Deletion/flagging is not what this argument was about). If you are not willing to, I understand. I am sorry if this issue caused any sort of distress.

Comment: I wrote the two answers with something like a year in between. If I write an answer to the exact same question I almost all the time will write different things —it depends on the time I have available, what I had for breakfast and the position of the planets. This byzantine analysis of answers is entirely pointless.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to flag Mariano's answer for being a link-only answer because it doesn't refer to a link, it provides a book reference which cannot become deprecated like links. His answer correctly answers the OP's question, specifically the OP's request for a history lesson. What better history lesson on notations than Cajori's definitive work on the subject? It is too much to ask for the "essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference" because it is not at all clear to me what is the essential part of the history of the notations for derivatives. And if there is/are any essential part/s then I'm confident that it revolves around the content of the other answers - in this way, Mariano's answer works well as a complement to the other answers, a point in favour of not flagging it.

If the answer was flagged as link-only because of its length, then I agree with Mariano that a good deal of common sense should be applied when enforcing the rules of MSE. A short bibliographic reference to a deep subject is a perfectly good response to a question asking for a reference. That it doesn't come with a summary attached does not detract from its usefulness in any way.

Comment: The question did not ask for a reference (the tag was applied after the answer, and not by the asker). The question asks *why* the notation is used, hypothesizing historical reasons as one possible answer. Note that the accepted answer does not talk about history at all. Further, the literal meaning of "link only" you use partially misses the point a bit. It is true that by now the answer is complementary to other answers, and thus arguably by now it is alright, but when it was given it was the only answer.

Comment: @quid Suppose the question is not tagged (reference-request) and there are no other answers to this question. Then, would his answer pass muster? Yes, I think a question that asks for a history lesson is adequately answered by providing a book reference that contains the precise details that the OP seeks. From your comment, I think that you read the question as asking only for some possible historical motivation in addition to other reasons. I don't agree with that: I take the words "history lesson" to mean just that. So, Mariano's answer is appropriate from my perspective.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that an answer which has as content solely a reference can be "as self-contained as it can be". It is the exact opposite of whatever "self-contained" is intended to mean. Also, "I think a 'link-only' answer is discouraged for two reasons": this is not true. There are many reasons for so, and arguably even more reasons (or at least different ones) for a book reference, which is the case (see the extended comments below my answer and the answer itself).

Comment: And if it is indeed "too much to ask for the 'essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference' because it is not at all clear (...) what is the essential part of the history of the notations for derivatives.", then the question is probably (most certainly) too broad. This does not make it a bad question per se, but an improper question to the site, as per explicitly stated by the site itself.